# Help needed with complex numbers: Plot $|z-1|<|z|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having difficulty visualizing this problem. So far I have tried:
$$|z-1|<|z|\Leftrightarrow (z-1)\overline{(z-1)}=|z|^2-z-\overline{z}+1<|z|^2$$

I don't get what to do with this expression next.

Comment: note that $z\cdot z^* = |z|^2$

Comment: You are on the right track! Now use $z=x+iy$ and get an inequality for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Geometric method:**

What this equation is saying is that given a complex number $z$, the distance between $z$ and $1$ is less than the distance between $z$ and $0$. I.e. $z$ is closer to $1$ than it is to $0$. So draw the line that is equidistant to $1$ and $0$ (namely the line $Re(z)=1/2$) and note that the required region is the one including $1$.

---

**Algebraically:**

You have $|z|^2-z-\bar z+1<|z|^2$. Moving things around, you get $$1<z+\bar z\\1<2\,Re(z)\\Re(z)>\frac12$$
This agrees with the geometric intuition given above.

---

Note: I used the following step. Given $z=a+bi$, $$z+\bar z=(a+bi)+(a-bi)=2a=2\,Re(z)$$

Comment: @ John Doe, I am very pleased if you ask my question about your answer. Is $Re(z)$ is positive or negative? Thanks.

Comment: @soodehMehboodi I've just read the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409381/find-all-z-in-mathbbc-such-that-zz-1) you posted recently. In your question, the inequality is the other way around compared to this question. So to see an answer to your question, just flip all the inequality signs that you see in my answer above. Then $Re(z)<\frac12$, so for your question, $Re(z)$ can be positive (but less than $1/2$, or it can be negative.